# Three.js: Having problems loading most images onto the back-side of a sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to Three.js and this is my first real project and as such I have been having issues which are probably quite simple to fix yet I have been stuck on this issue for 2 weeks. I have been trying to make a model of the Earth in Three.js complete with stars, the only problem is every image I have tried so far other than the Earth image simply doesnt work with the second, large sphere.

This is the image I am using for my Earth:
https://sos.noaa.gov/ftp_mirror/land/blue_marble/blue_marble/4096.jpg

These are some images I tried for the star field:
https://pm1.narvii.com/7090/6314dd7daedcc9bbb46da6f8ac7b7e5f4b44cecfr1-600-378v2_hq.jpg
https://i1.wp.com/www.ournewearthnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/wallpaper.wiki-Galaxy-Background-HD-PIC-WPC-PIC-MCH0113800.jpg?fit=3864%2C1808&ssl=1

```
<script>

        //pre stuff
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
        camera.position.z = 5;

        const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xF6FBFF );
        scene.add( ambient );

        // main code

        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2,72,72);
        var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('Earth.jpg');
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: texture});
        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        sphere.rotateX( .4 );
        scene.add( sphere );



  var geometry2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10,72,72);
  var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    material2.map   = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('star-map.jpg')
    material2.side  = THREE.BackSide
  var StarMap = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );
  scene.add( StarMap );

  //animations

        var animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            sphere.rotation.y -= 0.002;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        };


        animate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue, but to be honest I don't really know why what I did worked. My solution was altering the image through photoshop which leads me to believe it has to do with the photo's size.

This went from a comment to an answer if for some reason people payed attention, this is because I am unexperienced with Stack Overflow